# Why is nic renaming every reboot? - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, netplan

It was enp4s0, now it's enp10s0, and what was enp9s0 is now enp5s0.

I'm getting scared to reboot as that might kill networking until I KVM to it.

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Since I have my 10G nic bridged as br0, I have had to change it from enp4s0 to enp10s0 to get that to work. Here is the config maybe I have it wrong. The way the forum treats text as code acts extra spaces, in reality I have the spacing correct for the yaml file.

```
    network:
  ethernets:
    enp10s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp10s0]
      addresses: [10.1.1.254/24]
      gateway4: 10.1.1.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
            stp: true
            forward-delay: 4
  vlans:
    vlan.20:
      id: 20
      link: enp5s0
      addresses: [10.10.10.2/24]
```

_

```
#ifconfig | grep enp
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

- 

```
# dmesg | grep enp
[    0.512047] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: renamed from eth0
[    3.532720] mlx4_core 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.789093] mlx4_en: enp5s0: Link Up
[  470.823880] mlx4_en: enp5s0: Link Down
[  471.688577] mlx4_en: enp5s0: Link Up
[  990.440296] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered blocking state
[  990.440297] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered disabled state
[  990.440336] device enp10s0 entered promiscuous mode
[  990.454325] mlx4_en: enp5s0: Steering Mode 1
[  990.469279] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device enp5s0
[  990.492621] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device enp10s0
[  993.472880] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: igb: enp10s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[  993.688400] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp10s0: link becomes ready
[  993.688465] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered blocking state
[  993.688467] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered listening state
[  997.824093] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered learning state
[ 1012.928185] br0: port 4(enp10s0) entered forwarding state
```

Comment: These device names are supposed to be based on hardware topology so should not change between boots unless you have physically moved hardware around.  What kind of machine is this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the networking subsystem is not matching the hardware with previous boots.

I use the following to give a consistent name regardless of the physical type.

network:
ethernets:
eth0:
dhcp4: false
match:
macaddress: 
set-name: eth0
version: 2

Comment: Thank you comrade, that resolved it.

Comment: 'Consistent device naming' is definitely a case of the' path of good intentions' it works very well most of the time..  But its good to have an override when it doesn't..